Circles crossing every cell of an 8x8 grid
What is the least number of circles you need to draw, such that every cell of an 8x8 grid is crossed? A circle crosses a grid cell if one of the points on its circumference lies completely inside the cell (on the border doesn't count).
Standard version: circles may lie outside the grid. Bonus version: circles cannot lie outside the grid.

"one of the points on its circumference lies completely inside the cell": I don't understand what "completely" is meant to exclude. Can part of a point lie inside a cell?

I think it means it must be inside the cell, not on the border.  This excludes literal "corner cases".

Added clarification about meaning of "inside". Added bonus version

@DBS not sure what you mean?

And what happens then?

Here is my first try.  I wonder whether one can do better.

 

(actually it is not true.  My first shot was 16 small circles...)

I'm pretty sure this is optimal.

Bonus version: (I claim without proof that this is optimal)

 


Do the circles go inside the corner cells?

@DmitryKamenetsky It looks they do if the orange circles have radius less than $2+\sqrt2 \approx 3.414$, and on the flips side the four cells diagonally adjacent to the corner cells are hit when the radius is at least $8 - 2\sqrt6 \approx 3.101$, so we have some wiggle room in which every cell is crossed.

Same here.  I calculated that with circles having a radius of 3.277 and tangent to the borders, it matches best the image and the corner squares are covered.  It works also with 3.166 even though it differs a bit from the image.

@DmitryKamenetsky yes

What do you think the optimal number is for n by n grids?  For n=8 you have 5 already.

@Simd I am wondering about this question too. I think it is worthy of a new puzzle, perhaps for n=1 to 20.

@DmitryKamenetsky I would feel bad posting it. Would you be happy to?

Done. Thanks for the suggestion. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126173/circles-crossing-every-cell-of-an-nxn-grid

I think the correct answer is 4 but I don't know how to draw the solution. Anyway, you can imagine the 8x8 grid as four 4x4 grid and, for each of these, draw a circle that cross all 4x4 squares, like the blue circle in Sunny Lu's answer.

That would not cover the four corner squares of each 4x4.
