Circles crossing every cell of an NxN grid
What is the least number of circles you need to draw, such that every cell of an NxN grid is crossed? A circle crosses a grid cell if one of the points on its circumference lies completely inside the cell (on the border doesn't count). Circles cannot lie outside the grid. What are the best answers for N = 1 to 20? Partial answers are welcome.
An earlier puzzle was about N = 8. This puzzle was suggested by Simd.

I am pretty sure the best solution will be concentric circles.

@FlorianF agreed, I'm constructing an answer under that assumption but I think it may be hard to prove this is the best method

@FlorianF This is an extension of the bonus version. Concentric circles only work up to N=6.

@BeastlyGerbil See previous.

@DanielMathias oh interesting, didn't expect that. Tempted to continue the answer for the method anyway as its quite interesting maths but don't know if it would be worth it

Oh I didn't see the "inside only" condition.  Then it becomes less trivial.  Or not trivial at all.

If you can enumerate the sets of cells that correspond to circles, the problem can be solved via set covering.  See this related question for lines instead of circles: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756401/minimum-number-of-straight-lines-to-cover-n-times-n-grid

@RobPratt That would be great! I feel you are the expert for this.

It is funny, because originally I considered of making the puzzle about line crossings, but dismissed it because I thought it would be too easy. I thought the answer would always be N.

I think I am still a fan of concentric circles.  Modulo some adjustments for the corners.
Here is a 20-grid covered with 14 circles.

 


Answered at exactly the same time I asked about symmetry on the other answer :)

Symmetry has a big advantage, you only need to check 1/8th of the figure.

FWIW I calculated that the largest $N$ with a central circle that intersects the four corner cells but is still contained is $N=6$ (actually 6.828).

Daniel Mathias also found 6 is the max.

Oh yes, and Misha Lavrov too.

Very nice solution. What are you best results for other N using this method? I think we will need to make a table to record all the results.

UPDATE:
I found some nice symmetric solutions:
N = 12

 

N = 14

 

N = 18

 

I found some new solutions
N = 12

 

N = 13

 

N = 14, love that circle that breaks symmetry

 

N = 15

 

N = 16

 

N = 17

 

N = 18

 

N = 19, my biggest breakthrough

 


Knowing how much I had to fiddle for my 20-grid, respect for the tedious work this must have been.

I wrote a program to find these, so it was doing most of the tedious work for me :)

Oh, ok.  Then I take back what I said :-P .  But this explains why you didn't use more symmetry.

I didn't want to restrict it so it could find the symmetry (or not) if needed. But I should try to use symmetry to simplify the search.

The center of an odd-sized grid is a problem because symmetry means it is covered by 4 circles.  (or one very small one).  I wouldn't be surprised if solutions for odd-sized grids end up less symmetrical.


My best effort: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 11, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 20, 22. The larger ones are definitely suboptimal.

This is excellent work and I love all the graphics! Let's see if anyone can do better.

Can 1 to 6 be done with only concentric circles? I am interested in how much symmetry it is possible to preserve.

Making a community wiki so that all the answers are kept in one place. Anyone can edit it.



N
Circles (Current Best Known Upper Bound)
Credit




1
1
trivial


2
1
trivial


3
2
user1502040


4
2
user1502040


5
3
user1502040


6
3
user1502040


7
4
user1502040


8
5
Sunny Lu


9
6
user1502040


10
6
user1502040


11
7
user1502040


12
8
RobPratt


13
9
RobPratt


14
10
Dmitry Kamenetsky


15
11
Dmitry Kamenetsky


16
12
Dmitry Kamenetsky


17
13
Dmitry Kamenetsky


18
14
Dmitry Kamenetsky


19
14
Dmitry Kamenetsky


20
14
Florian F




@RobPratt I hope you will show us your solutions.

Guys please post your solutions first, before updating this table.

Here are two solutions that yielded the best-known values (not necessarily optimal).
$N=12$:

 

$N=13$:

 


Have you got an integer programming formulation now?

@Simd No, I just solved an ILP over a large set of randomly generated circles, not all possible circles.

@RobPratt I have a stupid question. From this large set of random circles did you remove duplicates - circles that cross the same squares?

@DmitryKamenetsky No, and I also didn’t explicitly remove dominated sets of cells. The ILP solver will do this automatically.

Instead of a selection of completely random circles, how about restricting it to (a random selection of) circles with their centre on a line of symmetry of the square? (i.e. diagonals and vertical/horizontal lines through centre) The best solutions seem to use only such circles, so maybe that gives better or faster results.
